# Fastest Way to query folder content titles and ids of Google Drive with java api?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to make a folder browser dialog for Google drive in my android app. The program should fetch all file/folder titles and the ids for the corresponding folder.
I have working code but it is not really fast; I query the title separately for each child:

```
do {
                try 
                {
                    ChildList children = request.execute();
                    List<ChildReference> items = children.getItems();

                    for (ChildReference child : items) {
                        String title = client.files().get(child.getId()).execute().getTitle();
                        listOut.add(new DriveFile(child.getId(), title));
                    }
                    request.setPageToken(children.getNextPageToken());
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                    callerActivity.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), COMPLETE_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
                    request.setPageToken(null);
                }

} while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

Comment: Have you checked on this reference? https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/ListFilesActivity.java

Comment: It will list all files inside one folder, but you could iterate by accessing all its children folders. With that said, each query for retrieving the information is going to take quite a while if you got several files and folders on Drive.

Comment: Yes, this works with the android api. But I am using the Web Api for Java, because I need to have access to all Drive files.